# How to create a new File object using image stored in 'mipmap' folder?

Tags: android

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
File file = new File("@mipmap/test.jpg");
```

Hope anyone could help.

Comment: I think you need to convert it to bitmap, then only save it as file.

Comment: Well, `mimap` is intended to store the *app icon* **only**. And NOTHING else.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? Could you also work with an `URI`, a file descriptor or an input stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can't create a file inside resource folders

If you want to create file from drawable, you need first to generate bitmap and then save bitmap as file.

Something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo, null)).getBitmap();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(filename))
```